# Error in OAuth dialog

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-oauth

When I redirect the user on

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
  client_id=" + APP_ID +
  &redirect_uri=" + CALLBACK_URL +
  &scope=" + "read_mailbox" +
  &state=" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
```

the server receives the error

```
error_reason=user_denied
   &error=access_denied
   &error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.
   &state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Is this an error that you're seeing in testing, or one in a production environment?

I ask because it sounds like the user is denying your application's request for authorization: following the link to authorize your application, but then deciding not to once they're on Facebook's OAuth page.  Is it possible that that's what's happening?

Comment: In testing, and i see it after request. But i dont deny Facebook autorization. So i don`t know why this happens.